# Programmatically check for a user group

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

How do you check a user's group in x++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AX 2009 the key class is UserInfoHelp.
This contains methods such as userInUserGroup and getUserGroups